# Why is this Azure SQL query extremely slow?

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a small table with about 1 Million rows and I am running the following query against it.

```
SELECT *
FROM TillBasicData
WHERE companyid = 'BE_AA'
AND languagecode = 'eng'
AND noos14 LIKE '%09258384374953%';
--09258384374953,09258387354952
```

The problem is that it takes close to 1 minute to execute.

I added the following index to try and speed things up

```
CREATE INDEX IX_TillBasicData
    ON dbo.tillbasicdata (companyid DESC, languagecode DESC, noos14 DESC);
```

This helps a bit and takes it down to about 30 seconds but I still don't get why it takes so long, I can only assume it has to do with the LIKE statement but what can I do to speed things up?

On such a small table I would assume the query to execute in less than 1 second.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get your 1sec idea from. Do you feel you have enough DTU's that it should be that fast? Anyway... it's unlikely to use the `noos14` part of your index so you may as well remove that. Also it's got to fetch the records and push them back to you and you might have slow network. How many records are returned? Is it any quicker of you use `select count(*)`?

Comment: It always returns 1 row and only ever 1 row so network should not be the issue here, not sure how many DTUs this instance has have to ask the infra guys when they return but for such a small table how many DTU wold be recommended?

Comment: I don't know how many DTU's you need but I guess you have the lowest amount of DTU's. Certainly 1 minute to return one row from a million rows is excessive. Could you temporarily put the exact `noos14` value in with your existing query and see how fast that is? Also use CTRL-L to see if it's doing an index seek? Does this table have a clustered index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of problems here:

- Unknown amount of columns you select from your table
- Like you said, `LIKE` statement.

To do proper analysis, it'd be best to see an execution plan, bust this is quite common problem, so I'd say that there's two things that might be happening:

- A full table scan based on your condition
- Nonclustered index seek based on `companyid` and `languagecode` and a filter predicate based on `noos14` and a key lookup operator, which retrieves all other columns from table that are not in index.

So in order to solve your issue, just change your index to include all required columns and replace `SELECT *` with an explicit list of columns you need.

Comment: When you say change the index to all required columns do you mean the ones in the select or the columns in the where clause or both?

Comment: @MattDouhan I should've been more specific on this. There's a special keyword `INCLUDE` in `CREATE INDEX` operator. This will store data in the leaf node of the index, but won't index these fields. Basically it has to look like this: `CREATE INDEX IX_TillBasicData ON dbo.tillbasicdata (companyid DESC, languagecode DESC, noos14 DESC) INCLUDE (col1, col2, col3);` where `col1, col2, col3` is whatever is in your `SELECT`. Also, column can appear only in indexed columns list or in included columns list.

Comment: There we go :), elapsed query time 0.67 seconds, I changed to specific columns for the select and changed the index as per your advice and boom that was it

Comment: @MattDouhan Great success! Also, you could move `noos14` to included columns, `LIKE` with wildcard at the beginning won't make use of index anyway. You'll safe some disk space there without sacrificing performance. And if you want to go even further, make sure that your data types are as small as possible, this won't make a big impact in your case, but is considered a good practice.